Why is my React application continuously making requests to YouTube API after initial render?
I am struggling to understand exactly what is going on with the Youtube API.
It seems the application I developed in React continuously makes requests to the Youtube API even after initial render is done. I had to go back and refresh my understanding of useEffect and realized that it was set up correctly and then even after I implemented a way to cache the initial requests, it seems to still be making requests from what I can tell in the network tab and obviously thats eating up my quota.
I started to notice it after I developed a custom hook to store my fetching of 8 very specific videos from YouTube. This is my useVideos custom hook:
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import youtube from "../apis/youtube";

const useVideos = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState(() => {
    const cachedVideos = localStorage.getItem("cachedVideos");
    return cachedVideos ? JSON.parse(cachedVideos) : [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videos.length === 0) {
      fetchSpecificVideos();
    }
  }, []);

  const fetchSpecificVideos = async () => {
    try {
      const videoIds = [
        "VIDEO_1",
        "VIDEO_2",
        "VIDEO_3",
        "VIDEO_4",
        "VIDEO_5",
        "VIDEO_6",
        "VIDEO_7",
        "VIDEO_8",
      ];
      const videoData = [];

      for (const videoId of videoIds) {
        const response = await youtube.get("/videos", {
          params: {
            id: videoId,
            part: "snippet",
            maxResults: 8,
          },
        });
        if (response.data.items && response.data.items.length > 0) {
          videoData.push(response.data.items[0]);
        }
      }

      setVideos(videoData);
      localStorage.setItem("cachedVideos", JSON.stringify(videoData));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching videos:", error);
    }
  };

  return [videos, fetchSpecificVideos];
};

export default useVideos;

NOTE: I did replace the actual ids with what you see above.
In my actual api file I have the following:
import axios from "axios";

const KEY = "my-youtube-api-key";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
  params: {
    part: "snippet",
    maxResults: 8,
    key: KEY,
  },
});

I am adding a screenshot of the network tab, perhaps I am misunderstanding what is going on, but to me that looks like a lot of requests for just 8 very specific videos that load once on app render. This is happening with or without the localStorage implementation:

I am wondering if this is a case for some type of memoization.
A colleague suggested that if multiple (N) components are using the custom hook of useVideo then all of those components will initiate the asynchronous request, that makes sense, however, only the parent App component is making use of that custom hook. I am posting the App.js component here:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import VideoList from "./VideoList";
import VideoDetail from "./VideoDetail";
import useVideos from "../hooks/useVideos";

const App = () => {
  const [selectedVideo, setSelectedVideo] = useState(null);
  const [videos, fetchSpecificVideos] = useVideos();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videos.length === 0) {
      fetchSpecificVideos();
    }
  }, [videos, fetchSpecificVideos]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (videos.length > 0) {
      setSelectedVideo(videos[0]);
    }
  }, [videos]);

  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <div className="ui inverted menu">
        <Header />
      </div>
      <VideoList
        onVideoSelect={setSelectedVideo}
        videos={videos}
        selectedVideo={selectedVideo}
      />
      <VideoDetail video={selectedVideo} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

The custom hook is not being utilized in any other components.

Question, is that behavior you described happens on initial app load when localstorage data is empty, or even happens after that? Initially when localstorage is empty and videos are [] - fetchSpecificVideos will happen as many times as you used this hook (for visible/rendered components). To make it better - you need to add a Context, that will hold all the data and functions, wrap the app with that Context, and rewrite this hook to rely on values and functions in the Context, that way it will act close to singleton.

@SergeySosunov, this was happening without any localStorage involved. I added localStorage to cache the fetched specific videos so that it would stop fetching, but it does not seem to work. Does that help clarify what is going on? Thanks in advance.

You've a "mounting-only" where the effect runs on only the initial render. What in your code is possibly being remounted to re-run your custom useVideos hook? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

@Daniel My point was that if your localstorage is empty, on user first visit, and multiple (N) components are using your hook, then all those components will initiale (N * videos_count) asynchronous requests to youtube api, and only after this async operation is done - they ALL will write some data into localstorage and only then this data is "cached". Thats why Im suggesting to add a top level Context to keep data and loading of that data, so you will have only 1 top component that is responsible to load and keep the data. And then just consume that data via hook or useContext.

@SergeySosunov, ahh, thank you for that clarification. I understand now, but Sergey, to be clear, only the App component is making use of the useVideo custom hook, would it help if I shared that file?

First issue: fetchSpecificVideos is not declared with useCallback hook and used in a useEffect dependency array of App component. Because of that - every time the App component is rerendered due to some state changed - fetchSpecificVideos function is recreated with new reference and that forces useEffect to re-execute, and if a rerender and re-execution is happened due to some other unrelated state change and before videos are populated - additional youtube api calls will be executed.
If you really need to use that method outside of the hook - wrap fetchSpecificVideos with useCallback or do not put it inside useEffect/useCallback dependency array:
const fetchSpecificVideos = useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    const videoIds = [
      "VIDEO_1",
      "VIDEO_2",
      "VIDEO_3",
      "VIDEO_4",
      "VIDEO_5",
      "VIDEO_6",
      "VIDEO_7",
      "VIDEO_8",
    ];
    const videoData = [];

    for (const videoId of videoIds) {
      const response = await youtube.get("/videos", {
        params: {
          id: videoId,
          part: "snippet",
          maxResults: 8,
        },
      });
      if (response.data.items && response.data.items.length > 0) {
        videoData.push(response.data.items[0]);
      }
    }

    setVideos(videoData);
    localStorage.setItem("cachedVideos", JSON.stringify(videoData));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching videos:", error);
  }
}, []);

Next and the main issue - you have a useEffect to call fetchSpecificVideos if videos.length === 0 both inside the hook and inside App component which is.. redundant and eats your actual quota.  It would be better if useVideos hook was only one who can call that said method, do not export fetchSpecificVideos from it, just call it inside.
Also I'll duplicate my comment here for future readers:
if localstorage is empty, on user first visit, and multiple (N) components are using your hook, then all those components will initiale (N * videos_count) asynchronous requests to youtube api, and only after this async operation is done - all of them will start writing that fetched data into localstorage and only then this data is "cached". Also, all of them will call setVideos method with same but different in terms of references array, which can affect other useEffects. Suggestion is to add a top level Context that will load and keep the data and then just consume that data via hook or useContext.
